# Android Things (0.5.1) fails to initialize GPU on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Tags: boot, hdmi, android-things

I have just set-up a Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things using the latest developer preview (5.1). It boots and I can run some minimum samples, and the output can be seen normally in a HDMI screen. So, everything would 'seem' fine.

However, any animation (Activity.invalidate) lags the whole UI for nearly 200msecs. I started looking, and got this from the debug console at start

```
   [2.281393] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
   [2.285374] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
   [2.290170] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
   [2.295648] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
   [2.301427] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
   [2.310873] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
   [2.318909] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
   [2.326573] [drm:vc4_hdmi_bind] *ERROR* Failed to get pixel clock
   [2.332823] vc4-drm soc:gpu: failed to bind 3f902000.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops): -517
   [2.340620] vc4-drm soc:gpu: master bind failed: -517
```

Also, when I try to set up a TextureView, even if I force it (via manifest or explicitly) to be hardwareAccelerated, it complains:
"A TextureView or a subclass can only be used with hardware acceleration enabled."

According to what I have read, the issue with hardware acceleration in Android Things for Raspberry PI3 has been fixed since developer preview 5. Just for information, the same thing happens running that version

The Android Things image that runs on the RPi3 is a standard build, without any custom modification, just a build from the latest version.

My question is: am I wrong with my assumptions, or it should work correctly with current Android Things version? If so, must any setting be edited? Pls tell me if I need to provide any additional info in order to clarify/solve this.

Comment: did you find a solution here? Or do you still have this issue?

Comment: Not solved yet. I haven't experimented more since I don't know if changing some settings would solve it or on the contrary there is nothing to do. Will wait for next release. Do you have the same issue?